# Dynamic CASE WHEN in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a list of Conversations, that come from multiple pages as below:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "page_id": 1,
        "name": "name 1",
        "assigned_user_ids": ["user1"]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "page_id": 2,
        "name": "name 2",
        "assigned_user_ids": ["user2"]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "page_id": 1,
        "name": "name 3",
        "assigned_user_ids": ["user2"]
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "page_id": 2,
        "name": "name 4",
        "assigned_user_ids": ["user1"]
    }
]
```

Imagine that "User 1" is calling the query, and User 1 **can get all items of page_id = 1** (because user 1 is administrator), but in page_id = 2 he/she
**only get the items that has been assigned to**, in this case is item with id = 4.

So when user 1 query, what I want to received is:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "page_id": 1,
        "name": "name 1",
        "assigned_user_ids": ["user1"]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "page_id": 1,
        "name": "name 3",
        "assigned_user_ids": ["user2"]
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "page_id": 2,
        "name": "name 4",
        "assigned_user_ids": ["user1"]
    }
]
```

This is my existing query in SQL look like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Conversations
WHERE PageId IN (1, 2)
```

Can any one tell me how to modify my SQL to resolve my problem?

Thank you very much!

Comment: So you have all those entries in a single JSON column?

Comment: Please add table structure and column type? And is this data has JSON or it is output result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OR` It will either give you what is on page one, so everything from there, or everything that has been assigned to userId 1. So effectively only the things that have been assigned on every other page.

```sql
SELECT * FROM Conversations
WHERE PageId = 1 OR userId = 1
```

If you want to restrict this to only some pages, you can still use `IN`.

```
SELECT * FROM Conversations
WHERE PageId = 1 OR userId = 1 AND pageId IN (2,3,4)
```